# How to get start date and time from uptime

Tags: java

I know how much time has elapsed in second. From that how to get the start date and time.

For example, I know 1600 seconds has passed.

From that how I can find out what is the start date and time using JAVA API.

Comment: Read the documentation for [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) or [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `Calendar` instance, `add` `-1600` seconds to it.  Get the `time` from it...

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, -1600);
Date date = cal.getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run the `uptime` command using [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774432/starting-a-process-in-java) of how to start a process and read its output from Java. From there, it's just a matter of parsing the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the difference between the current time and the uptime in milli-seconds.

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - System.nanoTime()/1000000;
System.out.println(new Date(startTime));
```

in my case this prints

```
Wed Jul 24 22:33:55 BST 2013
```