# Gradle run multiple jars at once

Tags: java, jar, gradle

This code executes each  run task one at a the time

```
...
task run1 (type: JavaExec, dependsOn: classes) {
    main="com.package.Main1"
    classpath sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
    classpath configurations.compile
}
...

task runAll(){
    dependsOn run1
    dependsOn run2
    dependsOn run3
        ...

}
...
```

How can I  run multiple Main classes from one jar file  at once (parallel)

Comment: Kick off multiple processes?

Comment: sounds good the question is  how

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774432/starting-a-process-in-java . Or just Google starting a process in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Gradle 1.9, Gradle can only run task from different projects in parallel. You can implement your own task and execute the main methods in parallel *within* that task, possibly using the `Project.javaexec()` method. However, you'll have to implement this yourself, for example with the `GPars` library.