# Java Code to open to RUN (windows + R) and execute a command

Tags: java

My scenario is to open RUN window (Windows + R) and execute it programatically using java.

Please provide me the java code for it or suggest me how to proceed with it.

Steps:

1. open RUN(WINDOWS + R).
2. Run a program (say C:\ProgramFile\Internet Explorer\iexplorer.exe) using it.

Comment: why would you use the Run Window to execute a command? Just execute it.

Comment: See this stack for how to just run a command: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774432/starting-a-process-in-java

Comment: why not just execute the command? why you want to open run?

Comment: sorry if i was not clear with my question. Let me explain it in detail. I am opening a .lrr(Load Runner Results) file. I was asked to open this file via RUN(windows + R) so that we can give input values here itself . But i want to do it programatically using java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
    "\"C:/ProgramFile/Internet Explorer/iexplorer.exe\" your_file.lrr"
);
```

Also you can add more parameters like this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
    "\"C:/ProgramFile/Internet Explorer/iexplorer.exe\" your_file.lrr /t /p foo"
);
```

Probably you have to watch out for the blanks in the path to your executable by adding double quotes (as you can see in my example).

Comment: Thanks @bobbel , the code you gave above was the one i was expecting, it works fine.....:)