# How can I open an external Java console application with arguments, capture output and execute commands on it?

Tags: c#, java, winforms, batch-file

I have a Java .jar application that is ran from a .bat file to have arguments passed to the Java application. The application opens a console (cmd.exe to be exact), writes things to it regularly and accepts some commands. I'm trying to create a kind-of wrapper around it in C# Winforms to ease it's use. How can I run the .jar with the same arguments as are in the .bat file, capture realtime output and write execute commands?

Comment: You can do this using the [System.Diagnostics.Process class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process). What have you tried so far?

Comment: @pasty I haven't tried anything so far, only looked up if it could be done. I won't bother starting the project only to find out what I want to is impossible.

Comment: It is possible. Since it is a fairly common operation, every widely spread modern programming language supports such a feature, [Java for example supports it too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774432/starting-a-process-in-java).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do this using the [System.Diagnostics.Process class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process) and the [ProcessStartInfo class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from the .NET Framework. The *Process* class is used to control (start / stop) the desired process (application) and the *ProcessStartInfo* class is used to configure the process instance that will be started (arguments, redirect input and output, show / hide process window, and so on).

The code for starting a jar file looks like this:

```
var jarFile = "D:\\software\\java2html\\java2html.jar");
// location of the java.exe binary used to start the jar file
var javaExecutable = "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre7\\bin\\java.exe";

try
{
    // command line for java.exe in order to start a jar file: java -jar jar_file
    var arguments = String.Format(" -jar {0}", jarFile);
    // create a process instance
    var process = new Process();
    // and instruct it to start java with the given parameters
    var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(javaExecutable, arguments);
    process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
    // start the process
    process.Start();
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
}
```

The usual way to [start a jar file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/run.html) is:

```
java -jar file.jar
```

To be sure, that the process will *find* the (in this case java) executable, it is a good practice to specify the fully qualified path to the process you want to start.

In order to redirect the **standard output** of the application you are starting, you need to set the [ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput) to `true` and then use the [Process.StandardOutput property stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput) to fetch the output of the started application. The modified code for the application from the example above looks like this:

```
// command line for java.exe in order to start a jar file: java -jar jar_file
var arguments = String.Format(" -jar {0}", jarFile);
// indicate, that you want to capture the application output
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
// create a process instance
var process = new Process();
// and instruct it to start java with the given parameters
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(javaExecutable, arguments);
process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
// start the process
process.Start();
// read the output from the started appplication
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
process.WaitForExit();
```

If you want to control the input too, set the [ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandarInput property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `true` and then use the [Process.StandardInput property stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to send input data to the started application.