# How to run python in java code on unix

Tags: java, python, unix

We have python application for work with WebSphere queue. This application consists of two files (**queue-tools**, **queue-tools.py**) and few libs. **queue-tools** file is looking like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

$HOME/sh/tests/queue-tool.py $@
```

When I run **queue-tool -h** command on unix host I see next result:

```
queue-tool.py [-h] [-t host] [-q qmgr] [-c channel] [-s SecurityExit] [-w]
                 [-f [FILE]] [-put arg [arg ...]] [-get arg [arg ...]]
                 [-peek arg [arg ...]] [-inquire arg]

Queue Tool

optional arguments:
  -h, --help           show this help message and exit
  -t host              target host
  -q qmgr              queue manager
  -c channel           channel
```

So my question is how to run this command (`queue-tools -h`) from java code and read output result? I use below code but it doesn't work:

```
public static void testScript() {
    String line;
    try {
        String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "queue-tool -h"};
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader in =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) { //line is null so nothing to read
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (InterruptedException iEX) {
        iEX.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioEX) {
        ioEX.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the p.waitFor().  If I am not mistaken, it makes it finish the process and then return to your thread, after which no output would be captured.

Comment: Here is the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774432/starting-a-process-in-java

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond p.waitFor() return 127 value.

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond could you please add answer on this question, just add above link and I update this question as answered.

Comment: @Paul I just put full path to queue-tool script, like this  `{ "/bin/sh", "-c", "/apps/scripts/sh/tests/queue-tool -h"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the p.waitFor(). If I am not mistaken, it makes it finish the process and then return to your thread, after which no output would be captured.

Just as reference I also found the solution at:
[Starting a process in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774432/starting-a-process-in-java)