# Get Chrome URL via Java

Tags: java, google-chrome

I am trying to get the URL from a Chrome via Java, I only need the URL as a Raw String. 
Is there any API which solves my problem ? 
Or is there any way i can get all http requests outgoing from my PC ?

Would be nice if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor you http traffic with tools like wireshark. If you want to do it in java, you can either use wireshark and read the txt log with java or you can leverage some java lib like: 
http://jnetpcap.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can start subprocesses with Java, see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3774444/4014509).

*If* there is an API in Chrome, that can be invoked via Shellscript (or Windows Command prompt), this is the way to go.