# jasperreport excel seen web browser

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

I am new jasperreport developper

I want to view excel report on web browser

My code is:

```
 final JasperReportBuilder jasperReportBuilder = ReportManager.getBasicReport("Ofis Durum Raporları", "", "");

  TextColumnBuilder < String > cityColumn = Columns.column("İl", "cityName", DynamicReports.type.stringType());
  TextColumnBuilder < String > townColumn = Columns.column("Avukatlık Ofisi", "townName", DynamicReports.type.stringType());
  TextColumnBuilder < String > stateColumn = Columns.column("Dosya Durumu", "fileState", DynamicReports.type.stringType());
  TextColumnBuilder < Long > countColumn = Columns.column("Dosya Sayısı", "fileCount", DynamicReports.type.longType());
  jasperReportBuilder.addColumn(cityColumn, townColumn, stateColumn, countColumn);
  jasperReportBuilder.setDataSource(Collections.synchronizedList(stateReportsDTO));


  response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
  response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=test.xlsx");
  try {
      OutputStream stream = response.getOutputStream();
      response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=test.xlsx");
      JasperPrint jasperPrint = jasperReportBuilder.toJasperPrint();

      JRXlsxExporter docxExporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
      docxExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
      docxExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, stream);
      docxExporter.exportReport();

      Response.ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = null;
      responseBuilder = Response.ok(stream);
```

But does not show up on web browser, it just downloads

if excel file show browser than i show excel file and that is not posible i run excel. Java Process class start with outputstream. Process class destination link : stackoverflow.com/questions/3774432/starting-a-process-in-java

Please do help me out here.

Comment: as far as I know there is no way by default to open excel in browser, just pdf, so this behavior is correct

Comment: I that so either i run Process to outputstream to excel  that is it posible

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My questions is if excel file show browser than i show excel file and that is not posible i run excel.  Java Process class start with outputstream.  Process class destination link :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774432/starting-a-process-in-java