# How perform "cloudformation package" command via java sdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-java-sdk

Here is [package](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/package.html) command description for cli. Can this command be executed via java sdk?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct equivalent in the SDKs, it's a CLI feature only.
You can invoke it like any OS command, i.e

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)
```

See example in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3774444/7401700

Use the overloaded form:

```
public Process exec​(String[] cmdarray,
                    String[] envp,
                    File dir)
             throws IOException
```

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String%5B%5D,java.lang.String%5B%5D,java.io.File)