# How to download youtube videos from a channel as soon as the video is uploaded using youtube-dl?

Tags: youtube, cron, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-dl

Here is my script to download a video if its video-id is known:

```
 youtube-dl -f 134 -ciw -o video.mp4 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxxxxxx
```

Is there any way by which I can download the latest video from now on from a particular channel as soon as the video is uploaded using cronjob or some other method?

Comment: You won't be able to access any YouTube video unless it is uploaded and made public. So simple answer to your question will be **No**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no method that is implemented into **youtube-dl** directly to download the latest video.

You can use the **Youtube Data API** to get the Channel's Upload Playlist-ID.

```
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list
```

After that you can periodically poll the Videos that are on the **Upload Playlist** of that Channel.

```
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list
```

There is an SDK for Java for example, so you could write a Java Application to retrieve the latest Upload, and then launch the youtube-dl Process like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774432/starting-a-process-in-java).

[Here is an example to retrieve your own Uploads using the Youtube API (just to get you started).](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java#retrieve_my_uploads)