# How can I start a Client and Server from one application using multiple processes?

Tags: java, multithreading, networking, process

I'm writing a JUnit Integration test that tests our networking protocols. I was initially using Threads and creating a Server on one thread and the Client on the other. I've been told this isn't the best way to test the networking system in place due to possible synchronization issues.

I was instructed that I should use Processes instead. I'm assuming this would mean running the Application on one process as a Server, and another process as a Client. This is easy enough to do manually; just start the application and set it as a server or a client then start the application again and run that as the opposite. But how would I create these two processes from within the JUnit test I'm writing? In multithreading, it's `new Thread(new Runnable()).start()`, then I'd continue from there.

Thank you!

Comment: Possibly related: [Starting a process in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3774432)

Comment: Yes but how would I go about it with a JUnit test?

Comment: You would start the server as a process in your test application first, then run tests against it, and finally terminate it when you're done

Comment: use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Comment: I ended up starting the processes using `Runtime` and running each test in the two processes separately, but synchronized. Thank you @Tony