# How to compile a LaTex file from Java program in Mac

Tags: java, macos, latex, pdflatex

i'm trying to use a terminal command `latex file.tex` to compile a .tex file. My program extracts the absolute path of the .tex file on a String:

```
public void generateLatex(String path)
{
    String file = path;
    //...compile file;
}
```

Is there a way to use the command on the given path? I tried using Process

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executable + path);
p.waitFor();
```

But it's not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Starting a process in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774432/starting-a-process-in-java)

Comment: I cant change the path, when I use Process to change the path it does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use Process builder:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("latex", "yourlatex.tex")
            .inheritIO()
            .directory(new File("your directory path"));
Process process = pb.start();
process.waitFor();
```