# Check if Linux "Screen" package is installed

Tags: java, linux, macos, gnu-screen

I'd need a way to check if the Linux Screen package is installed but through Java code. I would like to know if there's a built-in function for that? Also, the solution must be compatible with all major Linux distros & MacOS. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you thought of running [`which`/`whereis`/`locate`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/799776/what-is-the-difference-between-locate-whereis-which) in a [Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774432/starting-a-process-in-java)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the exit value of the command using `which screen`
in terminal if you issue the command

```
which screen 
echo Exitcode:$?
```

you get

```
/usr/bin/screen
Exitcode:0
```

also for a non existent command,

```
which screeeennn
echo Exitcode:$?
```

you get

```
screeeennn not found
Exitcode:1
```

Applying the same logic in the java class

```
        public class ScreenTest {
            public static void main(String args[]) {
                int exitValue;

                try {
                    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("which screen");
                    exitValue = p.waitFor();
                    if (exitValue > 0) {
                        // not installed mostly value will be 1
                    } else {
                        //screen present value will be zero
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't through about that. Thank you!

Comment: @Noushad Exitcode is 0 in both cases. It should be Exitcode:1 in the second instance

Comment: @Dimitry Changed it, thanks for reminding about it!